# How to use stack view to autolayout label and button?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

How can I layout a label and a button inside a `UIStackView` in such a way that the button only takes as much space as it needs and the rest is left for the label? Button text could be various length due to localizations.

The `UIStackView` here is *alignment: center* with *distribution: fill*.The only missing thing here is not stretching the button beyond the width needed for text and insets.

[image]

It doesn't seem possible with just the distribution settings. If *Fill Proportionally* is set the button must have a width constrain . Tried playing with the compression and hugging to no success, maybe I am doing something wrong.

**EDIT:** Found out why content hugging wasn't working. It needed a value >= 761 and not higher than 250 as I thought. Because 250 is the label content hugging value. Why 761? Can't really say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the Content Hugging priority of your button to something higher than 250. That way the button does not want to grow bigger than it needs to.

[image]

Comment: I did try it. Because you have provided evidence that it should work I made a new project and tried it there. It does work. I don't know what is wrong with my live project. Must investigate :/. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Show me your stack view configuration, maybe I can help

Comment: I found what was wrong. I needed >=761 content hugging on the button. Dunno why. When I tested I tested with 750 thinking that would be enough and then just gave up when it didn't work.